# Floating DIVs with auto-adjusting widths

Tags: css, html, css-float, width

I currently have the following HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix">
   <div style="width:33%;float:left">content</div>
   <div style="width:33%;float:left">content</div>
   <div style="width:33%;float:left">content</div>
</div>
```

When there are 3 divs on the one line, and because I specified a percentage width for each, they all fully occupy the width of the parent width.  What I am trying to achieve is to have the floating divs auto-adjust their widths (i.e. without hard-coding a percentage width) depending on how many divs are present on the line.  For example, if there are 2 divs, then each would occupy half of the entire width of the parent (i.e. 50%).  If there are 3 divs, then 33%.

Is this possible with floating divs?  If not, what other ways can I use to achieve this type of fluid layout?  I looked into making the parent use a 'table' display and the inner divs a 'table-cell' display, but then the parent stopped occupying 100% of the width available to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table approach worked fine for me, just remember to remove the `float:left` from the children divs, see my working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/DXGkb/).

Comment: Well, do I ever feel stupid.  I think I might have left the float definitions there.  Thanks Nelson!

Comment: Don't bother, we all made overlooks from time to time, but here you'll find plenty of eyes to spot them!.

Comment: How do you get this to play nicely when you have a `height` and `overflow-y: scroll;` specified as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to achieve the dynamic changes in the style:

```
var divcnt = $(".clearfix div").length;
var widthInPercent = 100.0 / divcnt;
$(".clearfix div").each(function() {
    $(this).css("width", widthInPercent+"%")
});
```

For an example see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eXqFS/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use css like

```
display:box;
```

fore parent div. And

```
box-flex:1
```

for nested. See  [this link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/) for sample.